# two level indented list with outline - how to continue text for a level1

Tags: itemize

using the outlines package (there is no label for it!), I need to create a two level list, where after the level 2 items the paragraph from the current level 1 continues. The desired output would be:

```
some text
  - level 1b
     = level 2a
     =level 2b
    continue on level 1 (no bullet here!!)
  - level 1b
```

The example code produces an unwanted bullet when the text for level 1 continues. How to fix this?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{outlines}

%opening
\title{x}
\author{xx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
some text
\begin{outline}
    \1 Either space   
    \1 Alternatively, space  
    \2 In some applications,  . 
    \2 In other applications,  . 
    \1 In both cases, space is modeled as a collection of spatial objects, which describe the boundaries of these objects\cite{Corbett1979a,Corbett1979b}. 
\end{outline}
More text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `outlines` package has a syntax like `\1[<custom label>]`. So just set the custom label to nothing for the item that should not have a bullet.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{outlines}

%opening
\title{x}
\author{xx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
some text
\begin{outline}
    \1 level 1b
    \2 level 2a
    \2 level 2b
    \1[] continue on level 1 (no bullet here!!)
    \1 Level 1b
\end{outline}
More text

\end{document}
```

[image]